# Picking a ball with a maximum number out of a bag of labelled balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Suppose there are $10$ balls in a bag labelled $1$ to $10$. Four are taken at random without replacement. What is the probability that the largest number seen is labelled $n$? ($4 \leq n \leq 10$).

My solution: We can pick $4$ balls from $10$ in $10 \choose 4$ ways. One of these must be labelled $n$. Then other three must have labels strictly less than $n$. Then We have $(n-1)$ for the 1st, $(n-2)$ for second and $(n-3)$ choices for third ball. Order doesn't matter here, hence we can pick these 4 balls with largest labelled $n$ in $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{3!}$ ways, and hence the probability is

$$\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{10 \choose 4}$$

Is this the correct way to approach the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct, with a good explanation.

The only note I have to add: Instead of considering the choices of $(n-1)$, $(n-2)$, and $(n-3)$ balls where order doesn't matter, we could just say that the other $3$ balls must be chosen from the $n-1$ balls with labels smaller than $n$, and there are ${n-1} \choose 3$ ways to do that. So the probability is

$$ P = \frac{{n-1} \choose 3}{10 \choose 4} $$

Of course ${{n-1} \choose 3} = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{6}$, so these are the same answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your observation about a slightly different way to view things. @aschepler